# In a simple Spring+Hibernate application,how to resolve "Unrecognized listener type"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I am trying to run an application with Spring(3.0.3) and Hibernate(3.6.10).

When I remove the line which creates the sessionfactory bean , it all works fine.
How to resolve the above exception ?
Am I missing any configuration/jars?

PFB my Spring Config file -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" default-autowire="byType">


<!-- Basic data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire="byType">
    <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> -->

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <array>
            <value>person.hbm.xml</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean class="com.impl.PersonServiceImpl" name="personService"></bean>
```

My Hibernate Mapping for Person  class is like this -

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.intf.Person" table="person">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
    <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"></property>
    <property name="address" column="address" type="string"></property>
    <property name="age" column="age" type="int"></property>
    <property name="dob" column="dob" type="java.util.Date"></property>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to run the above application using JUnit, below exception is coming -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unrecognized listener type [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unrecognized listener type [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.getListenerClassFor(EventListeners.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListener(Configuration.java:2451)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:763)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Are you running your tests using Maven? If so, make sure you have a proper test context set up under /src/test/resources.

Comment: No I am not running tests using Maven. Using spring and junit framework to run the tests

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve this issue with the below changes in Spring configuration file. I changed the auto wiring type to "byName" instead of "byType". I guess when we set autowiring byType, hibernate looks for the listener class "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor". But since no such class is present in either Spring 3.0.3 or Spring 4.1.0 version so it fails to load the sessionFactory bean -

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" **autowire="byName"**> 

<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="mappingResources">
    <array>
        <value>person.hbm.xml</value>
    </array>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bean creation exception,that means the class file is missing.Class file missing means corresoponding jar file/ configuration is missing.So you can check / make sure that the corresoponding jar file is missing from  maven pom.xml file or from jar folders.

maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```